# Express 404 page overlaps the react router

Tags: express, reactjs, routes, react-router

**Hello**

I have an express app running as a REST server, meaning all the `/api/xx` routes are process in express.

I also have a react app (served by express when accessing the `/`) as a client, which also has a router, the problem comes when i refresh a `react route`, the 404 page error of express shows up instead of the react page itself.

**The react router**

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={MainLayout} user={user}>
    <IndexRoute component={DocumentsPage}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="about" component={AboutPage}></Route>
      <Route path=":id/preview" component={PreviewPage}/>
      <Route path="upload" component={UploadPage}></Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

and when i access with a `<Link to="upload" </Link>` the page shows up, and when i refresh the page, i got the 404 express's page..

Any help would be lovely <3

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure a fallback, so that every request that doesn't exist in your Express routing is redirected to your React app at `/`. Here's a basic example of how to do that with Express:

```js
import fallback from 'express-history-api-fallback';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';

// Set up express
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const root = `${__dirname}`;

// History Fallback for express
app.use(express.static(root));
app.use(fallback('index.html', { root }));

// Listen
server.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```

Then you can also handle your 404 page with React Router.

Comment: Look like what i want, but cannot get it working with the index.html located at the ./public/index.html, how do i edit the fallback line to use my index.html ? thanks

Comment: Change the root folder, this line: `const root = \`${__dirname}/public\`;`